# Dropdownlist autopostback property is getting triggered even when I click any other options in gridview or on any other control on the same page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

**The dropdownlist and the gridview are on the same page.**

**Code for dropdownlist :-**

```
    <asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="drplist_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="true" ViewStateMode="Disabled" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
    ID="drplist" runat="server" DataSourceID="datasource1" 
    DataTextField="User_ID" DataValueField="User_ID">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Make a selection"/>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code for gridview :-**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gview" runat="server" Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="User_ID" DataSourceID="datasource">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="User_ID" HeaderText="User ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Name" HeaderText="User Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Email" HeaderText="User e-mail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Mob" HeaderText="User mobile number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Created" HeaderText="Created Date" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The dropdown has User IDs from the database and when a selection is made from the dropdown it fires it selectedIndexChanged event , **code for the same**:-

```
    protected void drplist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var index = drplist.SelectedValue;

        drplist.SelectedIndex = 0;
        Response.Redirect("~/Demo/TableDemo.aspx?User_ID="+index);

    }
```

Now when I click browser's back button , the dropdown still retains its selected value, **which I do not want**, I want it to reset to index 0. As I return to the dropdownlist from the **TableDemo.aspx** page and click on the edit button or delete button in gridview , the postback for the dropdown is triggered again taking me to the **TableDemo.aspx** page. Only a manual page refresh sets things straight. I tried to search and implement JS code for forcing page refresh on pressing browser back button but it didn't solve my issue and created more. I have tried using the update panel to my frustration and it happens to do nothing to solve my issue here. Sorry for the long post I couldn't do better in making the scenario shorter in writing here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your page cached, thats the reason it doesn't behave the way you want when you click the back button. Try to add this code to your page_load on the page you don't want to be cahched.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @chrillelundmark , thanks for sharing your response. I added the above mentioned line in the Page_Load method of the page where I have the drop down, but it doesn't seem to help.